# MySQL Removing Rows if One is Filtered

Tags: mysql, filter, row

I Have table like this:

```
id column1  column2
1    a        100
2    a        NULL
3    b        200
4    c        300
5    c        400
```

How can I select the rows without including those grouped rows that have at least one `NULL`.

Expected result:

```
id column1  column2
3    b        200
4    c        300
5    c        400
```

IDs 1 and 2 should not be included since they contain a `NULL` value for `column1 = a` value.

If a row has duplicate entry, ie., `column1 = a`, and those rows contain at least one NULL, don't include it the result set.

Comment: can u explain more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These sql will help ful to you.

```
select * from test where column1 not in (

SELECT column1 FROM test WHERE column2 IS  null GROUP BY column1)
```

Here [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2838f/2)

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You should make a sub query like this.

```
SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 IS null GROUP BY column1
```

Than you should select only that rows which NOT contains the sub select value in theirs column1 like this.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column1 NOT IN (SELECT column1 FROM table WHERE column2 IS null GROUP BY column1)
```

Comment: Well, that would include ID = 1, whereas it should not be included since ID = 2 with column1 = a is NULL.